# Return parameter passing in Julia

Tags: pass-by-reference, julia

If a Julia function returns an array, is the reference returned or a copy?

```
function pass(A::Matrix)
   return A
end
```

A real example is [`reshape`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.reshape):

> `reshape(A, dims)`
>   Create an array with the same data as the given array, but with different dimensions. **An implementation for a particular type of array may choose whether the data is copied or shared.**

How does the implementation determine whether data is copied or shared?

Comment: Could you add a link to the relevant section of the documentation?

Comment: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays/#Base.reshape

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pass` function above returns by reference, http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/ .

There is a bit more to the `reshape` example. 
For full arrays the reshaped array is a *new* array object that *shares* the same data. But keep in mind that there are plenty of specialized array types. The docs warn you not to rely on that because for example for a future implementation of immutable fixed sized arrays a different reshape mechanism could be used.